# Check an integer value is Null in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have got an integer value and i need to check if it is NULL or not. I got it using a null-coalescing operator

C#:

```
public int? Age;

if ((Age ?? 0)==0)
{
   // do somethig
}
```

Now i have to check in a older application where the declaration part is not in ternary. So, how to achieve this without the null-coalescing operator.

Comment: A point on nomenclature: `??` a null-coalescing operator. `SomeValueType?` is a nullable type.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Try answering as an regular answer!!!

Comment: You can try post on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: `int?` is ***not*** "an integer value". An "integer value" is *never null*, so the answer is simple: "it isn't". What you have is a `Nullable<int>`, or `int?` or just "a nullable int".

Answer (score 143, accepted):

`Nullable<T>` (or `?`) exposes a `HasValue` flag to denote if a value is set or the item is null.

Also, nullable types support `==`:

`if (Age == null)`

The `??` is the null coalescing operator and doesn't result in a boolean expression, but a value returned:

```
int i = Age ?? 0;
```

So for your example:

```
if (age == null || age == 0)
```

Or:

```
if (age.GetValueOrDefault(0) == 0)
```

Or:

```
if ((age ?? 0) == 0)
```

Or ternary:

```
int i = age.HasValue ? age.Value : 0;
```

Comment: Good answer; func fact, though: the parameterless `age.GetValueOrDefault()` is marginally faster - it *completely bypasses* the "do I have a value" check, and just returns the value field - which will have defaulted to `default(T)`, aka `0`.

Comment: @MarcGravell Cool, but for the purposes of the answer I chose to be explicit.

Answer (score 17):

Several things:

`Age` is not an integer - it is a *nullable* integer type. They are not the same. See the documentation for [`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) on MSDN for details.

`??` is the [null coalesce operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), not the ternary operator (actually called the [conditional operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)).

To check if a nullable type has a value use `HasValue`, or check directly against `null`:

```
if(Age.HasValue)
{
   // Yay, it does!
}

if(Age == null)
{
   // It is null :(
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can do this:

```
    public void CheckNull(int? item)
    {
        if (item != null)
        {
            //Do Something
        }

    }
```

Since C# version 9 you can do this:

```
  public void CheckNull(int? item)
  {
    if (!(item is null))
    {
        //Do Something
    }

  }
```

Or more readable:

```
  public void CheckNull(int? item)
  {
    if (item is not null)
    {
        //Do Something
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is already a correct answer from Adam, but you have another option to refactor your code:

```
if (Age.GetValueOrDefault() == 0)
{
    // it's null or 0
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because *int* is a ValueType then you can use the following code:

```
if(Age == default(int) || Age == null)
```

or

```
if(Age.HasValue && Age != 0) or if (!Age.HasValue || Age == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated above, [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is the null coalescing operator. So the equivalent to

```
(Age ?? 0) == 0
```

without using the [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) operator is

```
(!Age.HasValue) || Age == 0
```

---

However, there is no version of .Net that has [Nullable< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx) but not [`??`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), so your statement,

> Now i have to check in a older application where the declaration part is not in ternary.

is doubly invalid.

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022 you can do it like this:

```
public int? Age;

if (Age is == 0)
{
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

.ToString() method help you the same

```
public int? Age;

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Age.ToString()))
{
// do something
}
```