# Having a single default argument in a controller action expecting multiple

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My controller action expects several arguments, but only one can be nullable on POST. It is of type decimal. Based on the [research I've done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23245365/mvc-the-parameters-dictionary-contains-a-null-entry-for-parameter-k-of-non-n) for default routing, it looks limited to setting a default value for an action expecting a **single parameter**.

This is the response message I get due to this:

*MVC : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'z' of non-nullable type 'System.Decimal'*

Here is the method signature in BarController.cs:

```
[HttpPost]
public PartialViewResult Bar(int x, string y, decimal z) {*/Etc*/}
```

Here is the route I attempted but was not successful (RouteConfig.cs):

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "Bar", url: "Foo/Bar/z",
defaults: new {controller = "Foo", action = "Bar", z= 0 });
```

My request body has values for x and z, but y **can** be nullable.

#### How do I refactor so that z can be nullable? Apart from literally making it a nullable decimal type. I already have algorithms that subscribe to the Decimal type, not the nullable variant.

Comment: can you add your code here to make question more clear

Comment: Please, share your controller method code and also where you are calling it

Comment: @hasan I hav updated with code- thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your "int" or "decimal" parameters Nullable as well.

```
public PartialViewResult Bar(string y, decimal? z, int? x) {*/Etc*/}
```

Notice that in this case, you will have to validate the input in order of checking if "x" or "y" have values. In [Check an integer value is Null in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528107/check-an-integer-value-is-null-in-c-sharp) you can find some ways of validating a Nullable integer variable. The same approach could be used for checking if the decimal parameter is null.

Comment: Sorry about that, I pasted the wrong server error message. It complained about System.Decimal, not Int32- (see updated)

Comment: The solution is similar. You have to do the same (make the parameter Nullable) but with the decimal parameter.

Comment: Editing the answer to support both int and decimal Nullable parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you try to pass *null* as an int32, that will not work. In c# int32 is  a value type, not a reference. You could use nullable int32, but reading your question it sounds like you were expecting something different then an int32.

Add some code, and you will get help!

Comment: Thanks- I am dealing with decimal types fwiw. More code has been added.

Answer (score 0):

Use a nullable parameter like decimal? or int? in your action.